# Error 1064 in my sql even when the syntax to create table is correct

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

```
    CREATE TABLE Genere(gid int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   Desc VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(gid) );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Desc VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(gid) )' at
>   line 1

Comment: `desc` is a reserved word.  Use something else.

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Comment: Avoid using reserve word. "Best practice"

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your second column name. `Desc` is a reserved word, and the table cannot be used for the field name.

Answer (score 1):

It's found that a word used in your field list is in list of "Keywords and Reserved Words in MySQL"

Please refer the list of other words like these : [Keywords & reserved words in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)